# How to use google speech api in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-search-api

I have to develop an android application in which user speaks something and the wav file os send to the server where the googlespeech api shall return some text and i will display it on the android activity screen.

Note : Dont confuse urself with the android Text To Speech library i have to send the wav file
       to the client's server.

Problem : I have no idea of howsoever to use this API. I can record the voice from the client and save it in a wav file but don't know how to proceed.

Refer Link : http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't record a wav file and use it. At this moment the only way to do it is to get voice from the microphone using android intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-EN");
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE);
```

And then you can recievie the result in onActvityResult function:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        List<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

}
```

That is the basic idea.

Comment: well than in which format do i save the media recorded and cant i convert it to wav or something suitable so that i use google speech api for web and not TTS library for android??